# Is the Sacrificial Dagger like the other orbitals?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

The wiki description for the [Sacrificial Dagger](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Items#Sacrificial_Dagger) is:

> Dagger orbits Isaac, very high damage.

Does it also have the projectile blocking property of the other orbitals(i.e. Meat Boy or Halo of Flies)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sacrificial Dagger does **not** block projectiles. I tested this with an orange fire, a Sacrificial Dagger, and no other orbiting items. I watched the projectile pass right through the dagger several times.